# SendGrid not sending emails on Heroku from default inqury/contact form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actionmailer, refinerycms, sendgrid

This is my first app using RefineryCMS. The way I have sent mail from applications in the past is not currently work with my refinery app.

I have tried numerous ways of doing this by way of numerous searches on the internet and I cannot make this work.

Currently, here is what I have:

In the `environment.rb` file I have this:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '25',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => 'myusername@mydomain.com',
    :password       => 'mypassword',
    :domain         => 'mydomain'
  }
```

I have also tried:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '25',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => 'myusername@mydomain.com',
    :password       => 'mypassword',
    :domain         => 'mydomain'
  }
```

I have tried putting these settings in the production and development classes. Tried locally and on heroku but I just can't get the built in inquiry/contact form to send out the notifications emails and I have no idea why it won't work.

Like I said earlier, I have tried every solution (they are all very similar) I can find for this but can't make it work. If somebody could please tell what I am doing wrong and what, exactly, it is I need to do, that would be awesome.

Thanks in advance,
~Mike

Comment: In addition to your second attempt, did you put: ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, it was a bug in the existing version of refinerycms-inquiries that was causing the mail not to send. once I updated to 0.9.9.9, it worked as expected. In case anyone needs to know how to perform this update

Answer (score 6):

Actually, it was a bug in the existing version of `refinerycms-inquiries` that was causing the mail not to send. once I updated to 0.9.9.9, it worked as expected. In case anyone needs to know how to perform this update:

First, add this line to your Gem file:

```
gem 'refinerycms-inquiries',    '~> 0.9'
```

Then run this command:

```
bundle update refinerycms-inquiries
```

and this is all I added to the environment.rb file:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '25',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => 'myemail@domain.com',
    :password       => 'mypassword',
    :domain         => 'mydomain.com'
}
```

That's it.